# Sliding div left/right rather than up/down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Is there an easy way to make this into a sliding div that goes from left to right basing what code snippet I have provided below that is up/down?

So rather having it go up/down, make it go left/right?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");

    }); 

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });     

    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var  myDivWidth = $( "div#panel" ).width();

    $("#open").click(function(){
        $( "div#panel" ).css({'width' : '0' }).animate({width: myDivWidth}, 'slow');
    }); 

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $( "div#panel" ).animate({width: 0}, 'slow'); 
    });      

});
```

**Update :**

Here is the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ck4PX/ 
Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QGXQm/

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work...EDIT: okay, nvm, it works - however, I'm not looking for any animation to be called until I click the toggle fucntion or an <a href="#">open/close</a>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the animation on hide to slide it from left/right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, "slow");
    }); 

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, "slow");
    });     

    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot!  Would that work with jquery-1.3.2.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQueryUI and the [slide effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

Example:

```
$("div#panel").hide("slide", {direction: "left" }, 1000);
$("div#panel").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

Comment: If the above answer does not work, I'll give this a try.  Would I need the jqueryUI to be able to implement this code?

Comment: You would need to include jqueryUI.

Comment: Alrighty, I at the moment do not need jqueryUI for my project, but I'm sure I would down the road - when that times comes, I'll use what you posted as a reference so Thank you for helping out ;)